# google-app-engine static site example with protected pages

Tags: google-app-engine

I am wondering if there is an example of a static site running on google app engine which includes protected pages (that can only be accessed with authentication/authorization).  I have in mind something that might be similar to what [mod_auth_openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc) supports for the Apache web server.

If not, what might be the preferred way to go about such.

Answer (score 1):

The only built in authorization would be methods supported in your app.yaml (or equivalent) such as admin, login, none. Meaning an admin of your google cloud project, a valid google account, or public. There is no way to perform additional checks in a purely static site.